# How to build an incentivization model for a behavioural change using smart contracts?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens, private-blockchain

I have been researching various incentivization models and reading whitepapers regarding crypto-economics(e.g: steemit whitepaper) for a while but is it necessary to have a private blockchain for that purpose? Can't we use smart contracts on a public blockchain like ethereum to design such models and if yes then is there any resource for the same?